# How to perform UPSERT when loading data from Google Storage to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery support the following polices:

`WRITE_APPEND` - Specifies that rows may be appended to an existing table.

`WRITE_EMPTY` - Specifies that the output table must be empty.

`WRITE_TRUNCATE` - Specifies that write should replace a table.

None of them fits for the purpose of `UPSERT` operation.

I'm importing orders Json file to Google Storage and I want to load it into BigQuery. As logic suggests some records will be new while others already exists from previous loads and need to be update (for example update orders status (new /on hold / sent / refund etc...)

I'm using Airflow but my question is generic:

```
update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_orders_to_BigQuery',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    source_objects=[gcs_export_uri_template],
    schema_fields=dc(),
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
)
```

This code uses the `WRITE_TRUNCATE` which means that it delete the whole table and load the requested file.

How can I modify it to support `UPSERT`?

Does my only option is to query the table search for existed orders that appear in the json delete them and then perform the `LOAD`?

Comment: Hi. I don't think that's possible. There was a similar question in Jan and I can't remember it being updated since. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables

Comment: Correct, BigQuery does not support the `UPSERT` statement. The other question is still valid, but it might be worth pointing out that BigQuery now supports `MERGE` as part of its DML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google BQ - how to upsert existing data in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables)

Comment: @GrahamPolley can you explain about the merge DML?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: @GrahamPolley I read that. I meant in terms of if it's a solution for Big data or this meant to solve update of very few rows? I have around 200K rows that I need to INSERT\UPDATE per call. time/costs etc?

Comment: Great that you read it. Although DML will be slower than running analytical queries because it's more resource intensive, it will still scale. There are a few restrictions with the number of DML statements you can call however: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements

Comment: _"Specifically, you can issue a DML operation against an unlimited number of rows within a table in a big batch"_ https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/performing-large-scale-mutations-in-bigquery

Comment: @GrahamPolley is there a way to replace WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity   with update the whole row I have more than 150 columns. It's a nightmare to specify them all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of running a `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`, you could run a query that would give you the same result as an upsert.

Example from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement:

```
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
```

This query will:

- Take a look at table T (current) and S (updates).
- If the updates change an existing row, it will run an `UPDATE` on that row.
- If the updates have a not-yet existing product, it will `INSERT` that new row.

Now, how will BigQuery know about your table `S`? You can either:

- Load it into BQ into a different table with `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`.
- Or you can set up a federated table that looks straight into GCS - which I did in https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

Comment: Must I specify the fields in the update? I have more than 150 fields. I want it to update the entire row.

Comment: Use some Python to automate your query writing :)

Comment: How? There is no equivalent of insert into X (select * from Y) to UPDATE command.

Comment: I mean - don't write SQL by hand. Write code that will write the long queries for you.

Comment: that sound exhausting and inefficient?

Comment: Sounds like a great topic to discuss with the community in a new question :)

Comment: You can also do something like -        
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN        
          INSERT ROW

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` does not support `DELETE+INSERT *'`, yet. There is a feature request in G' issue tracker if you want to star it.

We also use AF and load orders too ;-). Because we want to keep the historical changes, we load into one table and then run a deDup query based on the primary key fields. 
Result is saved in a separate table (truncated). 
That table has the latest version/status of our order lines, which we then use for subsequent queries.

Lookup for dedup and `ROW_NUM()` for a SQL sample.

Note that depending on the volume, you may not need to materialize, a view or subquery may work just as good.