# UPSERT BigQuery

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I have a Bigqury table with 40 columns. I want to upsert data to it using PHP code. I have the data to upsert in an array of array as follows.

```
[
  0 => array:2 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "updated name 1 "
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "new name to insert"
  ]
]
```

I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables), there exists a `MERGE` command. 
I tried something like this.

```
MERGE dataset.table c
USING (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([(1, 'updated name 1'),
                             (3, 'new name to insert')])) d
ON c.id = d.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET c.name = d.name;
```

This fails, how can I populate data dynamically to d?
The array may have few needed column data.

I referred [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do UPSERT with partial columns (as long as these "ignored" columns are NULLABLE, which is default) for sure, see example below using temp table to demonstrate the idea:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE c AS 
  SELECT 1 id, "old name" name, NULL col1, NULL col2, NULL col3, NULL col4;

SELECT * FROM c; -- output before

MERGE c
USING UNNEST([struct<id INT64, name STRING>
              (1, 'updated name 1'),
              (3, 'new name to insert')]) d
ON c.id = d.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name) VALUES (d.id, d.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET c.name = d.name;

SELECT * FROM c; -- output after
```

Output before MERGE

```
+----+----------+------+------+------+------+
| id |   name   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+----+----------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | old name | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+----------+------+------+------+------+
```

Output after MERGE

```
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
| id |        name        | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
|  3 | new name to insert | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  1 | updated name 1     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Caveat**

Your query is subject to length limit. So don't UPSERT too many rows in one query.

> Maximum unresolved standard SQL query length — 1 MB

I also suggest you to use [query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#using_arrays_in_parameterized_queries) to pass your data instead of putting them in query.

**Scalability**

If daily update volume exceeds, say 200MB, likely breaking up the data into too many MERGE makes it closer to hit DML daily limit.

> Maximum number of combined INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE statements per day per table — 1,000

You should consider other way to do UPSERT. One of the ways is to upload a csv/json/parquet file to GCS and [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) to a BigQuery table, then do a similar MERGE statement from the table.

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you know to which endpoint of BQ I should send this?

Comment: What I provided is a query just like the one in your question, I'm not sure what "endpoint" were your referring to. Also, I added "Scalability" section, hope it helps.