# Insert data into BigQuery using native Insert query using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I Insert rows into BigQuery with the InsertAll method using JAVA. It is working always fine. But when we try to update the same row from the JAVA code am getting the below error,

> com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException UPDATE or DELETE DML statements over table project123:mydataset.test would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported

So I tried from BigQueryConsole.

I inserted a row using the **INSERT** query then immediately **UPDATE** the same row. It worked fine.

When I read the articles of BIGQUERY, they are mentioning both InsertAll from JAVA and INSERT query from Console using Streaming Buffer. In that case, the console query execution should be got failed.

Why Console query is working fine? But from Java InsertAll it is throwing me an exception.

It will be really helpful if anyone helps me to know the exact details.

If any suggestions to use Native insert query insertion from Java **instead of InsertAll** to BigQuery, It will be a great help.

Please find the code snippet

First am inserting the values to the BigQuery using the below code snippet

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "name");
map.put("2", "age");

BigQuery bQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(id)
            .build().getService();
InsertAllResponse response = bQuery .insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId).addRow(map).build());
```

Once it is getting inserted, am trying to update the row in that table with the following code snippet

```
String updateQuery = String.format( "UPDATE `%s` SET name = \"%s\" WHERE age = \"%s\")", name, age);
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();
bQuery.query(queryConfig);
```

Insert is working fine. when I tried to update the same inserted row am getting the streaming buffer error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It better if you can provide screenshots or stacktraces of the errors you get. It will be easier to understand the problem

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The error which I posted above only I am getting in my local. If you have gone through this kind of error please add your suggestions

Comment: Where did you read that the INSERT on the console add the data in streaming?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere When I tried to update the column (which I added using Insert query) via console is working fine.  But When I tried the same from Java API it is throwing the Streaming buffer error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Tabledata.InsertAll.html), it's clear that the insertAll perform a stream write into BigQuery.

When you use INSERT DML (`INSERT INTO <table> [VALUES....|SELECT...]`), you perform a query, not a stream write. So, the data management isn't the same. The performance are also different (Stream write can write up to 1 million of rows per seconds, the DML is query by query, and took more time for less data).

So, I don't know your code and what you want to achieve. But if you want to use usual query (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), use query API.

**EDIT**

I tried to adapt your code (but it was wrong, I took some assumptions) and I can propose you this. Simply perform a QUERY, not a Load Job or a Streaming write.

```
        String tableName = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";
        
        String insertQuery = String.format("INSERT INTO %s(name, age) VALUES (1,2)", tableName);
        QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder(insertQuery).build();
        bQuery.query(queryRequest);


        String updateQuery = String.format( "UPDATE `%s` SET name = \"%s\" WHERE age = \"%s\")", tableName, name, age);
        queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder(updateQuery).build();
        bQuery.query(queryRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can you please let me know the details of the query API? I added the code details above @guillaume blaquiere.

Comment: @Neela if you want to update rows please check following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables and let us know if it works for you

Comment: @Ines Thank you so much for your reply. I don't want to use MERGE or UPSERT Operation. From Java first I have to insert the data into the BigQuery table,  then I have to call the update call separately.   Am facing a Streaming buffer error. Is there any way to call the Native insert method query from Java as we are doing in Update?  or any other way to use with jobs in Java?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere Thank you so much. Let me try this and will share the details.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere,  am able to insert into the bigquery table. Thank you. But can you please let me know will it have any restrictions like per day 1000 records only be inserted or any limitations will be there if we use this native insert query in the code.  I have read DML queries will be having limitations. kindly add your suggestions.

Comment: Since several months, the DML are unlimited; previously you were limited to 1000 DML per day and per table, it's not yet the case. However, BigQuery isn't a relational database and it's not recommended to use it as website backend and to update insert lot of small piece of data. The latency is high and you create fragmentation (which is automatically defragmented periodically, but up to it, your requests are slower)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you so much for your reply. we can add records without any restrictions but if the overload increases it will be slower. Okay let me check on the same.