# Updating or replacing a row in BigQuery using Python?

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've created a cloud function using Python that receives some data and inserts it into a BigQuery table. Currently, it uses the insert_rows method to insert a new row.

```
row = client.insert_rows(table, row_to_insert)  # API request to insert row
```

The problem is that I already have data with unique primary keys in the table, and I just need one measurement value to be updated in those rows.

I would like it to update or replace that row instead of creating a new one (assuming the primary keys in the table and input data match). Is this possible?

Comment: You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables) about upsert in BQ

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is not designed for transactional data, it prefer append-only. Please refer documentation on Bigquery [DML quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables).  That means you can only apply a limited number of DML commands on a table per day.

Updating rows will not work on BQ tables.

***Recommended solution***:-

1. Create 2 tables (T1 & T2).
2. Insert All transactional records on T1 table, through your existing Function.
3. Then Write a BQ-SQL to read most recent record from T1 table and then insert most recent records to T2 table