# Google BigQuery - How to upsert using google-cloud-bigquery gem?

Tags: google-bigquery, rubygems

How to upsert using google-cloud-bigquery gem?

If not possible, how would I achieve it in a Ruby app?

Would I need to create a new table and copy unique rows to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose look at Bigquery `MERGE` [clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement).

> A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically

A good example for practical usage of this statement you can find in this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54120932/9928809).

I assume for Bigquery [Ruby client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery) would be enough appending the `MERGE` query statements to the appropriate `bigquery.query_job` [method](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/Google/Cloud/Bigquery/QueryJob.html) ultimately creating a Bigquery [Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview?hl=en) object.

Having some more doubts/concerns feel free to extend the initial question exploring more context about your current use case.

Comment: Thanks @nick_kh! This is very helpful and fulfil my needs.

Just want to double check that the MERGE will only work when there are already some data in a table otherwise there's nothing to compare/update/insert?

Comment: There is always option in `MERGE` clause to supply the three options: `MATCHED`, `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` and `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` flexibly setting the appropriate action, for more details look at the command [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement). Does it close to you question?