# Merge dataframe into Google bigquery using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to achieve something similar using spark and scala

Updating BigQuery data using Java
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data

I want to update existing data and also insert new data into Bigquery table. Any ideas if we can using some sort of DML within spark to do an `upsert` operation against BigQuery ??

I found that BigQuery supports `merge` but I'm not sure if we can do something similar using spark and scala
[Google BQ - how to upsert existing data in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark API does not support `upsert` yet. The best workaround at this moment is to write the dataframe to a temporary table, run a MERGE job and then delete the temporary table.