# How to perform the UPSERT operation using the python BigQuery client when writing JSON record

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am writing JSON records into a BigQuery table using the function `bq.insert_rows_json(f'{project}.{dataset}.{table_name}', rows_to_insert)`. This operation is done in `INSERT` mode. I was wondering if I could use the same function but in `UPSERT` mode. Is it possible ? I check the documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.24.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html) but did not find an argument for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google BQ - how to upsert existing data in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables)

Comment: Not really because I beleive it would force me to expand each JSON record into the SQL query there described. I would like to know if there is a in-built python function for this UPSET operation of a JSON query.

Comment: Can you provide sample data (that has a column for validation on uniqueness and sample json data) for proper replication of your use case?

Comment: Yes, here is a sample record :
    {
        "type": "App",
        "name": "00239_pipeline_name",
        "version": "-SNAPSHOT",
        "description": "Data Pipeline Application",
        "artifact": {
            "name": "cdap-data-pipeline",
            "version": "6.5.1",
            "scope": "SYSTEM"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find an in-built `UPSERT` function for python. However, you may try and consider the below approach which is derived from the comment of @Mr.Nobody.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query_job = client.query(
    """
    MERGE my-dataset.json_table T
USING my-dataset.json_table_source S
ON T.int64_field_0 = S.int64_field_0
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET string_field_1 = s.string_field_1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (int64_field_0, string_field_1) VALUES(int64_field_0, string_field_1)"""
)

results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

In this approach, you will be needing to ingest all of your supposedly "updated" JSON data on a table before inserting or updating them to your main BigQuery table. The query then will match each rows to the main table if the *primary ID* (uniqueness checker) is already there (then query will do `UPDATE`) or not yet (then query will do `INSERT`).

Screenshot of both tables before running the python code.

*Main Table:*
[image]
*Source Table:*
[image]

Screenshot of the Main Table when the python code finished executing.
[image]

**Conclusion:** The `int64_field_0` **4** was updated (from version 1.0.0. to 6.5.1) because it is already existing in the Main table. The `int64_field_0` **5** was inserted because it is not yet existing on the main table.