# İs it possible to create data pipeline with Google Cloud Data fusion using multiple database tables Update or Upsert?

Tags: cloud, etl, google-cloud-data-fusion, data-pipeline

After using multiple database tables plugin and load data to bigquery I would like to make incremental load for every table in one data pipeline.

I wonder if I can use UPSERT on multiple database tables plugin. How can I overcome any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPSERT operation is not currently supported in the B**igQuery Multi Table** Sink plugin.

One suggestion is to store records to upsert into another BigQuery Dataset and use a **BigQuery Execute** Action to execute one merge operation into the desired destination table per each of the source tables.

See [Google BQ - how to upsert existing data in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables) on how to execute the UPSERT operation using SQL.