# Is it possible to Upsert into Google BigQuery directly, instead of via Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: .net, google-bigquery

I have a simple list of some data (from MSSql / Postgres / No-Sql / CSV / whatever) and I wish to store this simple list of data into BigQuery.

```
public record SomeFoo(int Id, string Name, int Age);
```

Does BigQuery have an API that allows me to upsert the data, instead of just inserting the data and then causing duplicates? (NOTE: i'm totally happy that the upsert will update -all- the provided fields, per row).

Is this possible with the Google BigQuery nuget package (current version as of the time this question is being posted is v3.2.0)?

I found some code that ended up looking like this:

```
var insertOptions = new InsertOptions
{
    AllowUnknownFields = true,
    SkipInvalidRows = true,
                
};

var result = await client.InsertRowsAsync(datasetId, tableId, rows, insertOptions);
```

... but that method suggests that it's an Insert, only.

So can we do Upserts to BigQuery?

Comment: I don't believe so. There are UploadCsv, UploadAvro etc methods, but I believe they either truncate the table completely to start with, or append to it. I haven't seen anything for this in the BigQuery API... if you see something there and it's not currently supported in the .NET client, it would be easy enough to add it.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for the reply/help :) Outside of the .NET client, is there an API for it? Here's a similar SO post that suggests that BQ can do merges (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables) but not sure if this is exposed via an api? Or do I have to use Google Cloud Storage as a preliminary step?

Comment: As I said before, "I haven't seen anything for this in the BigQuery API" - that "merge" is just a query operation, so you can absolutely do that through the API, but that's for existing BQ tables. So I guess you could upload to a new table, do the merge, then delete one table? You might want to edit this question to make it non-.NET-specific so that people with more BigQuery API knowledge have a look.

Comment: (There are multiple BQ APIs, btw. The https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api would be worth considering, but I don't *think* that helps you here.)

Comment: Cheers @JonSkeet - and yeah, the post is really about .NET + GQ so if the .NET SDK can't do it, then it can't and I'll leave the question/answer as is. Big cheers, mate! ta!

Comment: Okay, if you want... but I suspect that if there *is* an underlying API call to do it, there'd be at *least* a way to fudge it a bit using the underlying Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 library. (And then I can add it into Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2...) The answer really is "not at the moment" for .NET - but that's not nearly as helpful as if someone with deeper (non-.NET) BQ experience can identify the relevant API call (which may have been added without me being aware).

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet - sorry to bother you once more. I did end up getting a solution working! Not sure if it's considered "an answer" but this is what I did with the C# SDK. 1) Export data to BigQuery as CSV using the `UploadCsvAsync` method. This returned a `job`. I then `PollUntilCompletedAsync` that job. What is important here is that I uploaded into a table with `WriteDisposition.WriteTruncate`. Then I can use a `MERGE` query to merge this "temp" data into the _real_ table. Seems to be working! The Merge is manual right now. So yeah .. this might help someone?

Comment: Right, that's basically what I was suggesting in the third comment here. As I say, there *may* be a better way of doing it with the BQ API directly, and I think we'd be more likely to find that out with a non-language-specific question. But if you're happy with what you've got, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

@Pure.Krome, As you have mentioned in the comment you were able to resolve the issue using the C# SDK by following the below steps.

1. Export data to BigQuery as CSV using the `UploadCsvAsync` method. This returned a job.
2. Then `PollUntilCompletedAsync` that job. What is important here is to upload it into a table with `WriteDisposition.WriteTruncate`.
3. Then using a MERGE query to merge this "temp" data into the real table. The Merge is manual right now.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.